# rails 4 devise sign_in doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using `rails 4` and `devise 3.5.2` to setup my project. Everything worked fine. Then I started working on applying boostrap theme. When I finished the `sign_in` page, I realized that sign-in doesn't work anymore. I can't understand what has changed.

When I try to sign_in, instead of getting redirected into the application, I am getting the 'sign_in' page again. It's as if sign-in is not performed at all.

This is view `app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb`:

```
<!-- === BEGIN CONTENT === -->
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row margin-vert-30">
      <!-- Login Box -->
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <form class="login-page">
          <div class="login-header margin-bottom-30">
            <h2>Login to your account</h2>
          </div>
          <%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, prepend: '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.html_safe %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, prepend: '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>'.html_safe %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
              </div>
              <%= f.alert_message "Please fix the errors below." %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <hr>
          <h4>Forget your Password ?</h4>
          <p>
          <a href="#">Click here</a> to reset your password.</p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- End Login Box -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controllers are fairly simple for users:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include UsersHelper

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    if admin?
      @users = User.all
    else
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    # @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @borrowers = @user.borrowers
    @current_total = current_total(@borrowers)
    unless @user == current_user
      redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied."
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :email, :role)
    end
end
```

This is my application controller with the redirect `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     user_path(current_user)
  end

end
```

And these are my development logs:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-17 18:26:47 +0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (41.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (248.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_pre_header.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_bg.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_primary_container.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_menu.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (56.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 426ms (Views: 370.1ms | ActiveRecord: 32.1ms)    

Started GET "/users/sign_in?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=xkWU%2BaWJpalPSmYJzGgpEG2%2BdoAFbaJQt133EPlWdJG9jBh3ZP3BYPpRkUzZZ6v21Qe%2BKdyaxo4HwBtHE%2BEseA%3D%3D&user%5Bemail%5D=atmosx%40me.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bremember_me%5D=0&commit=Log+in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-17 18:26:54 +0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xkWU+aWJpalPSmYJzGgpEG2+doAFbaJQt133EPlWdJG9jBh3ZP3BYPpRkUzZZ6v21Qe+Kdyaxo4HwBtHE+EseA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"atmosx@me.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (256.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_pre_header.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_bg.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_primary_container.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_menu.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (55.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 447ms (Views: 337.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

From rails console though, login works fine:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.2.2 :001 > ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
 => false
2.2.2 :002 > app.post('/users/sign_in', {"user"=>{"email"=>"atmosx@me.com", "password"=>"panagiotis"}})


Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-17 18:32:45 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (19.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"atmosx@me.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (24.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "atmosx@me.com"]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "sign_in_count" = $2, "updated_at" = $3 WHERE "users"."id" = $4  [["current_sign_in_at", "2015-09-17 15:32:45.844380"], ["sign_in_count", 2], ["updated_at", "2015-09-17 15:32:45.846407"], ["id", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://www.example.com/users/1
Completed 302 Found in 275ms (ActiveRecord: 57.8ms)
 => 302
```

Any ideas or hints would be welcomed!

UPDATE:

Going to a computer where I worked with an older branch, I think the problem is that *submit* in the current form issues a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request. But I'm not sure how to get over this..

Comment: According to [this post](http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2012/11/27/ror-devise-routing-error) might very well be a bootstrap related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing the form to make a POST request. In your form, fix this line to add method: :post

```
     <%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), method: :post) do |f| %>
```

If that doesn't help, as a hint, when you sign in through the form the request is being processed by `Devise::SessionsController#new` when instead it should done by `Devise::SessionsController#create`. That should help narrow down your problem, as I'm sure that's where it is. I hope that helps!

Comment: Tried that already. The problem is related to my bootstrap theme. I removed bootstrap all together (lost 4 hours of customizations) and now works. I'll go with workless for now.

Comment: Then I am sure that the problem isn't bootstrap itself. It must be that gem you are using to create the form. I recommend that you use Simple Form instead. It's pretty simple :-) https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Comment: You are correct. The problem is related to some sort of bad CSS...  `</div>` missing or something.